# How to increase the size of address bar and tabs bar in Google Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, tabbar

On a high resolution display, the location bar and tabs bar fonts are too small. Is there a way to enlarge them?

After searched in Google, I only find a way for Ubuntu https://askubuntu.com/questions/1100819/increase-the-size-of-address-bar-and-tabs-bar-in-google-chrome-screen-res-1920

Answer (score 2):

No browser has its own settings to deal with this.
Goto your computer's System Preferences (mine is iMac). Goto to Displays, go to Resolution, change from "Default for Display" to "Scaled" Chose a larger text option.  This will apply to all applications on your computer.
Your browser address bar and its font, will be larger but same will apply to the results. (You can use the normal means to reduce (or further increase) the results.)

Answer (score 0):

You are not completely right in that you can actually change the font size of tab names (i.e., for each tab, the font next to the logo of the size on the top of the browser window), but it's a hassle. Still doable.